# Magnetic levitation: completely zero friction or just very low and if the latter, what is the source of the friction?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am thinking of the now easy-to-obtain speakers where a spherical speaker is suspended above a platform. If this was in a vacuum and the sphere was spinning, why would it ever slow down? What is the source of the friction?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to spin the sphere in vacuum (and at the same time keep it from falling off if it goes out of the region with magnetic field), then **yes, the sphere will go on forever**. But if you did the same experiment at your (air filled) home, you might see that **the sphere eventually slows down**. The source of friction in this case is the *air resistance/drag*. It is somewhat similar to the friction we observe between solid surfaces, however in this case the surrounding air (instead of any solid surface) applies the resistive force on the speaker.